# NSMutableDictionary initWithContentsOfFile - null

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to create a NSMutableDictionary with the contents of a .plist. I have the following code:

```
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
NSObject *randomWord = [myDict objectForKey:@"Item 6"];
NSLog(@"%@", randomWord);
```

myFile and myDict are filled (not null), but when want to print randomWord (or myDict for that matter), it prints "(null)".

I've looked everywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```
self    MainViewController *const   0x068c0d60
myDict  NSMutableDictionary *   0x0000586c
myFile  NSString *  0x068c31f0
```

and the NSLog:

```
2012-05-10 12:26:22.302 project2[681:f803] (null)
```

So it seems myFile and myDict are filled, but randomWord isn't?

Edit #2:

NSLog(@"%@", myDict) prints:

```
2012-05-10 14:15:17.016 project2[2641:f803] (null)
```

So you're right, myDict is empty.

Comment: Why are you casting the item to NSObject and not to NSString, when it's supposed to be a word? Can you post a log of myDict?

Comment: I'm reading your question as saying that `myDict` is both not null and null.  Which should it be?

Comment: Johannes, log posted.
Philip, you're right, I'm sorry. myDict isn't null, but randomWord is. See edit.

Comment: If that really is the log that Johannes asked for, then contrary to what you state, `myDict` is null.

Comment: In that case I'm even more clueless...

Comment: @Sammy, do `NSLog(@"%@", myDict);` and let us know what the dict contains.

Answer (score 0):

remove space here in item 6

```
[myDict objectForKey:@"Item6"];
```

and if this not works try this one

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray* array = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
                                                         mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                   format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                         errorDescription:NULL];
if (array) {
  NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[array count]];
  for (NSDictionary* dict in array) {
    State* state = [[State alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
    [myDict setObject:state forKey:state.name;
    [state release];
  }
  NSLog(@"The count: %i", [myDic count]);
} else {
  NSLog(@"Plist does not exist");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 'State' or 'NSState'? When I use 'State', Xcode errors that 'State' isn't something he recognizes.

Comment: Oh 'NSState' doesn't exist either, for that matter.

Comment: Oh and the items are called 'Item x', space included. 'Item6' won't en doesn't work.

Comment: state is any object jst to combine the value and their keys, not predefined,

Comment: state is an object jst to store value and key, not predefined

Comment: But why does Xcode error then? I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i mean this class is jst i declared for my app. leave that and replace it wid myDic setObject:... forKey:what key u want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11097/discussion-between-sammy-and-the-saad)